# How to hook add_action() into after category description with id?

Tags: hooks, actions

I'm using newspaper theme for my web blog. I want to create post highlight into certain category. For example in this url: https://blog.bookingtogo.com/category/destinasi/wisata-domestik/pulau-bali/

I want to insert this code after category content or before post content.

I tried to insert shortcode from admin panel: post > category > bali. but not worked.

This is my code that i make:

```
  function balihighlight(){
    $post = get_post( 2183 ); 
    $title = $post->post_title;
    $excerpt = get_the_excerpt($post);
    $excerpt = substr( $excerpt, 0, 260 ); 
    $result = substr( $excerpt, 0, strrpos( $excerpt, ' ' ) );
    
    ?>
<style>
    .container{
        position: relative;
        text-align: center;
        color: black;
    }
    .highlight{
        position: absolute;
        background-color:yellow;
        margin-left: 25px;
        margin-top: 10px;
        width: 148px;
        left: -25px;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    
</style>
<div class="td_module_11 td_module_wrap td-animation-stack">
    <div class="container"> 
        <div class="td-module-thumb">
                <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post,'medium' );  ?>
            </div>
        <div class="highlight">HIGHLIGHT</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item-details">
        <h3 class="entry-title td-module-title">
            <a href="https://blog.bookingtogo.com/destinasi/tempat-wisata-di-bali/" title="<?php echo $title; ?>"><?php echo $title; ?></a>
        </h3>
        <div class="td-excerpt">
            <?php echo $result;  ?>
        </div>
        <div class="td-read-more">
            <a href="https://blog.bookingtogo.com/destinasi/tempat-wisata-di-bali/">Read more</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

    <?php
    
    
}
add_shortcode('balihighlight', 'balihighlight');
```

Is there any hook that can insert this code into after category content or before post content? for info: my bali category id is: 284. I hope I get the solution, Thank you very much.

Comment: It depends on what hooks are available in your theme. You will need to ask the author. Alternatively you could create a child theme and edit the templates directly.

Answer (score 0):

Check [this blog](https://njengah.com/the_content_wordpress-add-to-end-of-content/) about adding something before the post content. Here is the code you need to add in `functions.php`:

```
add_filter('the_content', 'add_content_before');

function add_content_before($content) {

      $before_content = "Your pre-content to be here";

      $fullcontent = $before_content . $content ;

      return $fullcontent;

}
```